# How to pick JSON array from a column in Sql in the below example

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

How to pick json object from below json array in sql. Example

```
[{“name”:”juhi”, “roll”: “1”, “subject”:”maths”},{“name”:”shubham”, “roll”: “2”, “subject”:”Physics”}]
```

How can I pick these json objects separately through a sql query.
Result I want :

```
{“name”:”juhi”, “roll”: “1”, “subject”:”maths”}
```

I had tried json_query & json_value but nothing works for me.

Comment: You didn't describe how you want to select that json object from the array, so I made a guess that you want to query it based on the value of one of the keys in the object. I linked to an answer that shows how to do that in MySQL 8.0. You also did not identify which version of MySQL you are using, so I assumed you are using the current version.